# Can we create a Local Administrator account for a pc in domain, by using a Domain Controller

Tags: windows

Can we create a Local Administrator account for a pc in domain, by  using a Domain Controller..

As of now am using Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Group policy should be able to do this and target the OU with the machines you want to create the user on.  Alternatively you could use WMI filtering to target specific machines by name.

Under a new Group Policy: user configuration - preferences - local users and groups - right click new user and enter in the details